# Excel VBA determine the location of a 3X3 range relative to activeCell

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I have a 3 x 3 range in Excel which is defined as a range. I would like to know where the user has clicked when double-clicking in any of the blue cells. - the area is defined as a range.

[image]

I have tried to create a function to find out this selection, however its a little difficult for my basic skills.

my idea is to assign an integer value (1 - 9) to each cell in the matrix and have a function to return that value.

> Edited question based on provided answer

```
Function relRange(rangeIn As Range, activeCell) As Integer
relRange = 0
If (rangeIn.Rows.Count = 6) And (rangeIn.Columns.Count = 6) Then  ' range has double merged cells
    ' comparison code to determine where the activecell is relative to the 3x3 array

        If rangeIn.Cells(5, 1).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 1 '1
        If rangeIn.Cells(3, 1).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 2 '2
        If rangeIn.Cells(5, 3).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 3 '3
        If rangeIn.Cells(3, 3).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 4 '4
        If rangeIn.Cells(1, 1).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 5 '5
        If rangeIn.Cells(5, 5).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 6 '6
        If rangeIn.Cells(1, 3).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 7 '7
        If rangeIn.Cells(3, 5).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 8 '8
        If rangeIn.Cells(1, 5).Address = activeCell Then relRange = 9 '9

End If
End Function
```

I have this function working now, was surprised that there was not an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be in your **Sheet Object**, not in a standard module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim Matrix(1 To 2) As Range, i As Long
    Set Matrix(1) = ws.Range("A1:C3")
    Set Matrix(2) = ws.Range("F1:H3")

    For i = LBound(Matrix) To UBound(Matrix)
        Set iSect = Application.Intersect(Target, Matrix(i))
        If Not iSect Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not iSect Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Target located in Range # " & i & " at: " & Target.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Does NOT interesect in any of my ranges!"
    End If

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

If `Cancel = True`, then your cell will not be in editing mode.

You can take the range from `Target` and make your comparisons with that.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works with me. however, I forgot to mention that I have many of these matrix views, I was trying to define a generic way of working.  at the moment, Address is relative to the sheet, not relative to the range.

Comment: @Hightower I updated my code. You would create a new range for each of your 3x3 blocks in the `Matrix(i)` range.